# 5-set scaled Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory, area

Let's assume that we have $5$ sets, each having up to $100$ elements. Some elements belong to multiple sets. Even more, there is at least one element for each of the $2^5=32$ configurations (by configuration I mean a vector of $0$s and $1$s indicating whether a specific element belongs to the corresponding set or not). Now I would like to represent these sets on a scaled Venn diagram. In other words, I want each of the $32$ regions of the Venn diagram have an area proportional to the number of elements that belong to it.

Is it always possible?

Now, more practical question: is there a (possibly, approximative) algorithm that would help to construct such a diagram?

Thank you.

Comment: There are 5 set venn diagram images that you can use. "Is it always possible?" -> Almost certainly yes, esp if you're doing by hand pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sure... and just stretch each region, as needed.

Comment: Your diagram only has 22 regions.

Comment: You cannot use circles for Venn diagram with more than 3 sets.